# Codeigniter MySQL a Join Query with a column name collision in the results

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, orm

I have a very common, run of the mill JOIN query where I have found my self in a bit of a pickle.

My CI DB Query looks like:

```
    $this->db->select()
    ->from('user_event')
    ->join('game_bridge', 'user_event.gmeID = game_bridge.gmeID')
    ->where('user_event.memID', $memID);
```

Now what I failed to realize up until about a minute ago, is that both tables have a "location" column, however both columns contain unique sets of data to the query results I am looking for overall. With that is there a way to give one location column or the other an alias so I can access the results object for that under a different property name?

If so, how can I do that with CI's DB class/helper?

Comment: Is CIs active record (or so they calls it) using is a must?

Comment: unfortunately, yes, in this particular project, at its current stage of development using the "CI" active record is a must. If it were up to me, I'd most likely plug Docturine into it, and run with that. Or Use Zend

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to get location from both tables you have to give an alias to one or both of them 
keep user_event location as it just give alias to game_bridge is like game_bridge.location as game_location

```
$this->db->select('location,game_bridge.location as game_location')
```

Comment: ah.. yea.. figures, I always forget you can do something in the `select()` like that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can set aliases in your query.

```
$this->db->select('user_event.location as u_loc, game_bridge.location as g_loc');
```

But in this case you must enumerate all fields you want to select.

Comment: Now would this limit my results in the concept of from the 2 tables I am ultimately wanting all the data from all the columns not just the locations column. Or is CI smart enough to know that I only want to do that with those 2 but otherwise still call out the rest or should I just follow suit for the rest of the column names in a similar fashion minus the alias for the ones that dont need them

Comment: You can do something like this: `$this->db->select('*, game_bridge.location as g_loc');`